# Android - extending ListActivity to add images for each item?

Tags: java, android, xml, image, listactivity

I would like to extend my simple ListActivity to have little images next to each item. Here is my code so far:

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="6dip"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" />
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    // Create an array of Strings, that will be put to our ListActivity
    String[] names = new String[] { "some", "list", "items", "which", "each", "have", "their", "own", "image"};


    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.main, names));


}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    // Get the item that was clicked
    Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    String keyword = o.toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, "You selected: " + keyword, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}
```

}

And I've got like 10 items (strings) and each of them has an image I'd like to put next to it, e.g. itemImage1.png, itemImage2.png, ..., etc.

How can I do this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this a while back. Used the LazyLoader found here [lazyloader](http://androidsnips.blogspot.com/2010/08/lazy-loading-of-images-in-list-view-in.html)

Looks to be the key code, overriding the `getView` method

```
 public static class ViewHolder{

        public TextView text;

        public ImageView image;

    }



    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi=convertView;

        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView==null){

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

            holder=new ViewHolder();

            holder.text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);;

            holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);

            vi.setTag(holder);

        }

        else

            holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();



        holder.text.setText("item "+position);

        holder.image.setTag(data[position]);

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], activity, holder.image);

        return vi;

    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I'm just kind of unsure how to implement this. What is item.xml file like? What is the data object? And what is this line: imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], activity, holder.image); ? Thanks though

Comment: looks like that data is a String[] of urls. imageLoader.DisplayImage will take the first argument (URL), download the image, and load it into the third argument (your list item).

The xml will need to include a textview and an imageview. Think of it as representing one row of your list.

You'll have to pass the activity and the string[] of urls into the list activity. If you'd like to pass in a string[] of text too, it'd be easy modifiable. I'd just download the code and poke around in it; if anything, it should be easy for you too implement without even understanding too much of the details.